# Outlook rule on forwarded mail exchange server

Tags: exchange, forwarding, email-filter

I'm forwarding my email on the exchange 2003 server from my old emailaddress to a new one.
The new one is not in that exchange 2003 server.

Example:
Old email = test@mydomain.com
New email = test@thisismynewdomain.org

When mail is sent to test@mydomain.com it arrives without any problem in the new mailbox.

However, I would like to set up a rule which replies to all users who send me email to test@mydomain.com

How can I do this? I would like to avoid using a computer(client) only rule.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your question how to put on an auto response, similar to an out of office?

Comment: Point is when an email is sent to the old email it pops in the new mailbox.

Comment: Then put the rule on the 'old account' saying "this mail box is no longer in use" and then forward it? I do this, it works fine. Or did I still miss the point?

Answer (score 0):

I'd add another server side rule for the old account, so that it:

1. Replies to the sender with a message you specify
2. Forwards emails to your new address

If you've already reconfigured Outlook to connect to the new server (you probably have), you should be able to do it by using Outlook Web Access on the old Exchange server and set up a new rule there.

Comment: How can I set server side reply?

Comment: Do you know how to access your email via webmail (Outlook Web Access)?  It should be something like https://server.domain.com/exchange/username - Once logged in, there should be a link to Rules.  The rules you specify there should be server-side.

Comment: I cannot reply with a rule there.